# Error: Compile Error: Expression must be a list type: String at line 446 column 44

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

i am trying validate the insurance number in salesforce , but i am getting below error

insurance = insurance.replace('A','01');

```
                Integer sum = 0;
                Integer numDigits = insurance.length() - 1;
                Integer cle = parseInt(insurance[numDigits],10);  =====>Error

                for (Integer i = 0; i < numDigits; i++) {
                    Integer digit = parseInt(insurance[i], 10); =====> Error
                    if (math.mod(i,2) != 0) {

                        digit *= 2;
                    }
                    sum += digit > 9 ? digit - 9 : digit;
                }

                if (math.mod(sum ,10) != cle) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substring` method of `String` to get the character at index.

Also, there is no `parseInt` in Apex. Use `Integer.valueOf` instead.

So, the first part of your code should be

```
Integer numDigits = insurance.length() - 1;
Integer cle = Integer.valueOf(insurance.substring(numDigits));
```

**References:**

- [Apex Developer Guide: String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)
- [Apex Developer Guide: Integer Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_integer.htm)